# How to correctly use Spark SQL caching in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I have a table of 40 million labels. I am running a Spark SQL query on Java in the following view. I am using disk caching, still the query is slower than a simple postgres query. Please correct my error if someone encountered such problems.

```
SparkSession ss = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("Sql spark session")
        .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dsRow = ss.read().format("jdbc").option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db_name")
        .option("dbtable", "tb_name")
        .option("user", "postgres")
        .option("password", "456")
        .load();
dsRow.createOrReplaceTempView("people");
dsRow.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
Dataset<Row> dsRowSql = ss.sql("select * from people where firstname like 'fi%s%n%m%' and surname like 's%rn%me'");
dsRowSql.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my grammar mistakes. But I didn't ask for it. I need specific solutions

Answer (score 0):

Several observations:

1. I don’t know how you measure your timings, but if you copy all the data in Spark, then query, it will be slower than just query the data in PostgreSQL. It would be interesting to measure where time is spent.
2. You can push the ingestion SELECT statement to PostgreSQL, so you don’t have to copy all the data to Spark, have a look at: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch08/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch08/lab300_advanced_queries/MySQLWithWhereClauseToDatasetApp.java.
3. If you want to experiment with caching and checkpoiting, which are ways to increase performance, look at https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch16, it should give you a good framework for evaluating optimization.
4. I am not sure you need to tweak with persist to disk, it may slow things down here:

   dsRow.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());